Python mock not asserting call when target method is called inside another method
I do not manage to do some basic assert_called() in a class where some methods are internally calling other methods.
Example code:
from unittest.mock import Mock


class Foo:
    def print1(self) -> None:
        print("print1 called")  # I see this print message
        self.print2()
        
    def print2(self) -> None:
        print("print2 called")  # I see this print message

foo = Foo()
foo_mock = Mock(wraps=foo)
foo_mock.print1()
foo_mock.print1.assert_called()  # OK
foo_mock.print2.assert_called()  # NOT OK

It seems that the problem is that in print1(self) the instance of self is of type Foo and not Mock. This is why there are not any registers about the mock calling print2.
Is this the expected behaviour? Usually, self is bounded to the caller object. Meaning that an instance of type Mock should be passed. I guess that the problem is because the instance was already created and therefore all methods were bounded to the non-mocked instance. I would expect this to be modified by the Mock's __init__.
Is there any solution to this? Am I doing something wrong?
EDIT:
I saw that the problem can be fixed by doing this:
import types
from unittest.mock import Mock


class Foo:
    def print1(self) -> None:
        print("print1 called", type(self))
        self.print2()
        
    def print2(self) -> None:
        print("print2 called")

foo = Foo()
foo_mock = Mock(wraps=foo)

setattr(foo_mock, "print1", types.MethodType(Mock(wraps=Foo.print1), foo_mock))  # FIX
setattr(foo_mock, "print2", types.MethodType(Mock(wraps=Foo.print2), foo_mock))  # FIX

foo_mock.print1()
foo_mock.print1.assert_called()
foo_mock.print2.assert_called()


The problem here is that the mock is "looking" only for the print_1. It is not inspecting to the other objects inside the print_1. If you want to mock everything, you should explicitly every thing. To look it, try to see what foo_mock.print1.method_calls returns. :-)


It seems that the problem is that in print1(self) the instance of self is of type Foo and not Mock. This is why there are not any registers about the mock calling print2. Is this the expected behaviour?

Yes.

wraps: Item for the mock object to wrap. If wraps is not None then calling the Mock will pass the call through to the wrapped object (returning the real result). Attribute access on the mock will return a Mock object that wraps the corresponding attribute of the wrapped object (so attempting to access an attribute that doesn’t exist will raise an AttributeError).

You are wrapping foo which is a real instance of the class Foo. Any attribute access will be real. Using wraps can lead to real I/O execution which your tests may not be expecting. Use wraps only when your tests depend on the real output.
